# Getting *error C4772: #import referenced a type from a missing type library; '__missing_type__' used as a placeholder*

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, import, 32bit-64bit, typelib

Getting *error C4772: #import referenced a type from a missing type library; '**missing_type**' used as a placeholder* when converting from 32 bit and visual studio 2008 code to 64-bit and visual studio 2010 platform. Actually, I am working on a large project having a solution comprising of 20 projects. I am working on simultaneously converting it from 32 bit to 64 bit platform as well as from visual studio 2008 to visual studio 2010 platform. Its arising at the #import of some .tlb file. I have tried running as Administrator also. When I checked I found that the correct file path is being associated with that particular .tlb file. Please help as I have spent much more time on it and couldn't find any solution to it.

Comment: You'll need to document the paths of these .tlb files better.  Some odds that it cannot find it because it is stored in, say, c:\windows\system32.  Visual Studio is a 32-bit program, it will be redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.  Something like that.

Comment: the path is documented in a correct way. I am telling you surely because when I right right click on the .tlb file in the code and select it for open, it shows that it really has got the correct path.

Comment: I'm getting this error with Visual Studio 2017, even though the TLB file is being imported and the TLH generated in the <configuration> folder.